# hardhat test console.log does not work

Tags: solidity, hardhat, testing

I'm trying to test one contract using console.log, but it does not work, the outcome its always the same, 0 passing...[image]

any help out there. i tried to use hardhatclean but did not work.[image: config]

im using the hardhat node,without any network param(the default one)
thank you!

here[image]

im trying to do the Ethernaut exercises, but console log does not work.
test file [image]
[image]

Comment: show us your test file and where it is stored

Comment: Please provide the code of the test you're running.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: im trying to do the ehternaut exercises but my console .log does not work always shows 0 passing!